# How to enable MVC 5 Razor template when adding view on VS2013 express

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

On my VS2012 I can view the MVC 5 Razor template when adding view. See attachment:
[image]

But when I'm using VS2013 express edition I can only see is the MVC 5 View Page Razor.
[image]

I already install everything but the rest razor template is not existing. Help please...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the top-most button in the `Add` context menu called `View...` (as can be seen in your second screenshot). There, you can choose from different options (partial/non-partial, use/don't use a layout view), but the option for a layout page is not available there. But you can just create a normal view and name it accordingly I guess.

Remark: My Visual Studio 2013 Premium additionally has the 4 buttons you are missing; I don't have VS2013 Express to check that as well.

Additionally, the context menu `Add` => `View...` can also be opened by right-clicking inside an action method in the controller to create a view in the corresponding folder (using a template). So you generally don't have to manually navigate to the *Views* folder.

Comment: yeah i know. just want check if do I need to set something on vs2013 express  in order the 4 buttons to be available. btw thanks dude!

Comment: Ah okay, I thought you might have overlooked that one ;-) I don't know if I made something special, which update is installed on your VS2013? I'm using VS2013 Premium Update 4 currently, and the only installed Plugin I'm using are the WebEssentials (maybe that has something to do with the buttons?)